# Elastic Search ,Kibana - Unable to get entire data into elastic search from Oracle database using JDBC Plugin

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, ojdbc

I have an oracle database over server, but when I try to index entire data into elastic search, the total count of database mismatch with that of elastic total hits. I don't know why. Primary reasons could be -1) Not selecting the time range appropriate to your index reference timestamp.
I have cross checked time range and still missing few thousand records out of 20 million (approx).

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:ORCL"
    jdbc_user => "system"
    jdbc_password => "oracle"
    jdbc_validate_connection => true
    jdbc_driver_library => "---\ojdbc6.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    statement => "SELECT  DISTNAME ||'-'|| DNO as Distributor, DISTNAME ||'-'|| DNO || '-' || STATE_NAME || '-' || DCNAME as Distributor_2,
col1, col2,col3 ---- from EPMUY_ELASTIC"

    } 
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "index"
    user => "user"
    password => "password"
  }
   stdout{
      codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

**Note** - I didn't create index mapping myself, I let kibana decide Index mapping (dynamic:true)

On server I checked the total count of records in database which is - 18331793

```
(select count(*) from table)
```

And the same count with my query with logstash pipeline also.
But on kibana I am only seeing 18,303,447 number of records.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that no one is running UPDATE, DELETE or UDPATE statements on the related table ? In general if the database is not read-only you can never be sure that running the same query returns the same number of rows even if you just run the same query in a very short time frame.

Comment: you should check the logstash log to understand which which documents are not indicized and why

Comment: Thank You So Much.. I checked the logstash log and got the answer. Thanks for Replying.